# Is there any way to disallow Robocopy to download files from OneDrive to a local backup?

Tags: windows, backup, onedrive, robocopy

I hope you can help me. I currently use Robocopy to back up my OneDrive files to a local hard drive with the following command:

```
robocopy Location1 Location2 /MIR /W:0 /R:1 /REG.
```

It works great. However, I noticed that when I do a clean install and I run it, it downloads absolutely everything in the cloud, taking up a lot of disk space in my device.

Every file "on demand" (not local but in the cloud) in OneDrive shows the modified date in their metadata. Is there a way for Robocopy (or any other command) to read this information to decide whether to copy or not without having to download all the files? Ideally, it would download only those files that have been modified. I don't know if I have made myself clear. If this is possible, do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Onedrive appears to change file attributes depending on whether they have been stored as sparse (Offline - "in the cloud") files or stored locally. It appears that they change from "ALP" to "ALOM" so you could potentially exclude "Offline files" by adding `/XA:O` to the end of your command. Would that suit your requirements?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
It does work as you explain by not downloading every file, but those files which were modified and are not manually downloaded are not copied

Answer (score 3):

You can omit those files that have the attribute "O" (online) set:

```
robocopy /XA:O
```